# Change base_link position

Tags: ros, base-link, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do we change the base_link coordinate centre on autoware? Is there a default one that it automatically uses? If so where is it positioned?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322696/change-base_link-position/) by [melanielim](https://answers.ros.org/users/41377/melanielim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-05-13**:
Can you expand on what you mean by "change the base_link coordinate centre"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Autoware coordinate system, `base_link` is defined at the center of rear wheels as follows.
[image]

You need to set the relative transform between `base_link` to `velodyne` on Setup tab.
[image]

---

Originally posted by [aohsato](https://answers.ros.org/users/41505/aohsato/) with karma: 36 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-15**:
Could I ask you to attach the images to your answer directly? I've given you sufficient karma for that.

**Comment by [aohsato](https://answers.ros.org/users/41505/aohsato/) on 2019-05-15**:
Greatly thanks. I've edited.